# Parsing unknown number nodes of a XML with namespace in PL/SQL procedure?

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql, xml-parsing, procedure

I have a xml_data which I am passing into procedure-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:a xmlns:ns2="http://www.sbc.com/iag/schemas/adapters" xmlns="http://www.sbc.com/iag/schemas/core">
     <ns2:b>

        <ns2:OrderNumber>99995</ns2:OrderNumber>
        <ns2:ServiceOrderNumber>88888</ns2:ServiceOrderNumber>

    </ns2:b>
    <ns2:b>

        <ns2:OrderNumber>99699</ns2:OrderNumber>
        <ns2:ServiceOrderNumber>88888</ns2:ServiceOrderNumber>

    </ns2:b>
    <ns2:b>

        <ns2:OrderNumber>69999</ns2:OrderNumber>
        <ns2:ServiceOrderNumber>88888</ns2:ServiceOrderNumber>

    </ns2:b
    <ns2:b>

        <ns2:OrderNumber>67999</ns2:OrderNumber>
        <ns2:ServiceOrderNumber>88888</ns2:ServiceOrderNumber>

    </ns2:b>
</ns2:a>
```

node

> ns2:b

can be repeated any number of times and is not fixed.
How do i fetch this

> ns2:OrderNumber

from this xml data in oracle procedure.I am able to fetch the value if

> ns2:b(ns2:OrderNumber)

occurs only one time through below code-

```
select extractValue(
  xml_data, 
   xmlns="http://www.sbc.com/iag/schemas/core"'
)   '/ns2:a/ns2:b/ns2:OrderNumber/text()',
  'xmlns:ns2="http://www.sbc.com/iag/schemas/adapters",
into order_number from dual;

  dbms_output.put_line('FailedRetry -' ||order_number);
```

But how do i keep iterating until I get all the values of that node

in XML.I have tried different solution posted on this site,but none worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [XMLTABLE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions253.htm#CIHGGHFB).

```
select y.* 
from dual,
xmltable( xmlnamespaces(default 'http://www.sbc.com/iag/schemas/core', 'http://www.sbc.com/iag/schemas/adapters' as "ns2"), 'ns2:a/ns2:b'
passing xml_data
columns OrderNumber varchar2(10) path 'ns2:OrderNumber',
    ServiceOrderNumber varchar2(10) path 'ns2:ServiceOrderNumber'
) y;
```

Sample query:

```
SQL> with x(xml_data) as (
        select xmltype('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:a xmlns:ns2="http://www.sbc.com/iag/schemas/adapters" xmlns="http://www.sbc.com/iag/schemas/core">
     <ns2:b>
        <ns2:OrderNumber>99995</ns2:OrderNumber>
        <ns2:ServiceOrderNumber>88888</ns2:ServiceOrderNumber>
    </ns2:b>
    <ns2:b>
        <ns2:OrderNumber>99699</ns2:OrderNumber>
        <ns2:ServiceOrderNumber>88888</ns2:ServiceOrderNumber>
    </ns2:b>
    <ns2:b>
        <ns2:OrderNumber>69999</ns2:OrderNumber>
        <ns2:ServiceOrderNumber>88888</ns2:ServiceOrderNumber>
    </ns2:b>
    <ns2:b>
        <ns2:OrderNumber>67999</ns2:OrderNumber>
        <ns2:ServiceOrderNumber>88888</ns2:ServiceOrderNumber>
    </ns2:b>
</ns2:a>')
from dual
)
select y.* 
from x,
xmltable( xmlnamespaces(default 'http://www.sbc.com/iag/schemas/core', 'http://www.sbc.com/iag/schemas/adapters' as "ns2"), 'ns2:a/ns2:b'
passing xml_data
columns OrderNumber varchar2(10) path 'ns2:OrderNumber',
        ServiceOrderNumber varchar2(10) path 'ns2:ServiceOrderNumber'
) y;

ORDERNUMBE SERVICEORD
---------- ----------
99995      88888
99699      88888
69999      88888
67999      88888

Elapsed: 00:00:00.03
SQL>
```

If you want to iterate each record, use it in a cursor.

```
decare
    cursor c1 is select y.* 
    from dual,
    xmltable( xmlnamespaces(default 'http://www.sbc.com/iag/schemas/core', 'http://www.sbc.com/iag/schemas/adapters' as "ns2"), 'ns2:a/ns2:b'
    passing xml_data
    columns OrderNumber varchar2(10) path 'ns2:OrderNumber',
        ServiceOrderNumber varchar2(10) path 'ns2:ServiceOrderNumber'
    ) y;
begin
    for i in c1
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line('FailedRetry -' ||i.OrderNumber || ' '|| i.ServiceOrderNumber);
    end loop;
end;
```

Comment: thanks a lot Eat,but when I tried to compile its showing error-Error(14,2): PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement,i'e at with x(xml_data) as line.

Comment: if u are using it in plsql, you should use it in a cursor.

Comment: but 'with' is also supported in oracle,isint it?It would be really helpful if you could show me how can i use cursor here.